# UICollectionViewLayout returning attributes and cell doesn't update

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a custom layout and in some random places I am getting weird behavior.
Here is the log I am getting: 
The rectForindex is my calculation to the attributes and the cell is where my cells actually are.
This happens after collectionview's reloadData which force all of them to re calculate

```
2015-01-26 21:23:46.815[558:125567] rectForIndex 0: 10.000000 35.000000 300.000000 200.000000
2015-01-26 21:23:46.816[558:125567] rectForIndex 1: 17.000000 25.000000 286.000000 200.000000
2015-01-26 21:23:46.817[558:125567] cellForItemAtIndexPath 0: 539.970276 8.354366 320.059448 256.979950
2015-01-26 21:23:46.818[558:125567] cellForItemAtIndexPath 1: 17.000000 25.000000 286.000000 200.000000
```

Comment: You need to invalidate the layout along with `reloadData`.